How can I call an API when my calendar (input type date) is closed?
How can I ensure that my API is called only when a date is selected from the calendar or when the Enter button is pressed after manually changing the date field, rather than on every change in a modal popup where I edit and enter data?
current code
date input
<Input
type={"date"}
className={`${validateFieldBorder(item.display_name)}`}
placeholder={""}
name={`${item.name}`}
onChange={onChangeField}
value={formData[item.name] ?? undefined}
max={new Date().toJSON()?.slice(0, 10)}
disabled={isDisabled}
/>

i have tried it to with onblur but even after i select a date from the calender the function i called with onblur wont work. Also tried using the onMouseDown it works for the lap but not in my phone.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use onBlur tag in input
you can use the onKeyPress event to detect when the Enter key is pressed
        <Input
  type={"date"}
  className={`${validateFieldBorder(item.display_name)}`}
  placeholder={""}
  name={`${item.name}`}
  onChange={onChangeField} // Call API when the input field value changes
  onKeyPress={(event) => { // Call API when the Enter key is pressed
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      onChangeField();
    }
  }}
  value={formData[item.name] ?? undefined}
  max={new Date().toJSON()?.slice(0, 10)}
  disabled={isDisabled}
/>


HI, I have tried using onblur, but when I open the calendar and select a date, the calendar closes without triggering onblur. It only triggers when I click outside the date after selecting it.

i have made change in code please check now

Using onChange to call the API causes it to trigger every time I manually type into the date fields, which isn't ideal. Therefore, onChange is not a suitable option in this scenario.
